# Do loop to find a match in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to create columns of RT1 to RT(last) with the difference between TSN's. The EV should be HIS and Previous EV should be HIS or OH then RT2=TS2-TS1 ELSE IF EV1 ne OH  then EV2=TS1 ELSE O.
 EV (having HIS) shoud match with decrement EV's to find match(OH or HIS), If find match then difference of TS's else go to next decrement to find match.

```
SlN EV1 EV2 EV3 EV4 EV5 EV6 EV7 EV8 TS1 TS2 TS3 TS4 TS5 TS6 TS7 TS8
1   OH  HIS HIS OH  OH  HIS OH  HIS 2   3   5   8   10  15  17  19
2   HIS HIS OH                      5   6   9                   
3   HIS OH                          1   3                       
4   HIS                             2                           
5   OH                              3                           
6   OH  HIS                         2   5                       
7   HIS HIS                         2   4                       
8   OH  OH                          3   4   6   9   9           
9   HIS HIS OH  HIS HIS             2   5   7                   
10  OH  OH  HIS
```

EX: SL:1 R1=0 (becoz EV1 ne HIS) , R2=TS2-TS1 (EV2=HIS,EV1=HIS or OH), R3=TS3-TS2 (EV3=HIS, EV2=HIS), R4=TS6-TS5 (EV4 ne HIS , EV5 ne HIS So, EV6=HIS (match found))

Output sample:

```
SLN R1  R2  R3  R4  R5
1   2   1   2   5   2
2   5   1           
3   1               
4   2               
5   0               
6   0   3           
7   2   3           
8   0               
9   3   1   3   0   
10  0   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you thinking something like this...

```
DATA dataout;
SET datain;

ARRAY Rvar[8] r1-r8
        Evar[8] EV1-EV8
        TsVar[8] TS1-TS8;

DO i=1 TO 8;
    IF i=1 AND EV1="HIS" THEN Rvar[i]=TS1; 
    ELSE IF Evar[i]="HIS" AND Evar[i-1] IN ("HIS", "OH") THEN Rvar[i] = TsVar[i] - TsVar[i-1];
    ELSE Rvar[i]=.;
END;
RUN;
```